# Ssh Python Module Gives Error When Trying To Import

Tags: python, ssh, module, syntax-error

I've been trying to figure out how to ssh using python 2.7 on a 64-bit Windows 8 computer. I found a module called ssh, so I used pip to install it. But when I type,

```
>>> import ssh
```

It gives me this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import ssh
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ssh\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ssh\transport.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ssh import util
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ssh\util.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ssh.common import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ssh\common.py", line 98, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  File "c:\users\sethco~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-u7gyec\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sethco~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-u7gyec\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sethco~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-u7gyec\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sethco~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-u7gyec\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\winrandom.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sethco~1\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-u7gyec\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win-amd64.egg.tmp\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\winrandom.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I'm not sure what it means. Did I install it correctly? How do I fix this? Are there any alternatives? I would appreciate your help very much.

Comment: Maybe you have 32-bit Python but the dll within the Crypto is 64-bit

Comment: What your computer is isn't the point. You can't load 64-bit libraries into a 32-bit process.

Comment: or the other way around: the dll there is 32-bit

Comment: Ah. So you mean I may have downloaded a 32-bit library?